# Pull list all issues (multiple pages) with Github API in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, get, github-api

So, I'm trying to get a list of all issues in my repository. The problem is that I don't know how to access the response header, and grab the other pages. What I have so far is:

```
var outhtml;
var repositories;
$.getJSON(uploadURL, function(json){
    repositories = json;
        outputPageContent();
});

function outputPageContent() {
    if(repositories.length == 0) { outhtml = outhtml + '<p>No repos!</p></div>'; }
    else {
        //console.log(repositories);
        outhtml = outhtml + '<p><strong>Repos List:</strong></p> <ul>';
        $.each(repositories, function(index) {
            console.log(repositories[index]);
            outhtml = outhtml + '<li><a href="'+repositories[index].html_url+'" target="_blank">'+repositories[index].title + '</a></li>';
        });
        outhtml = outhtml + '</ul></div>';
    }
    $('#ghapidata').html(outhtml);
}
```

but this only gets me the first page. I've done pagination to get issues before, but it was with python. How do I do it with js/jquery?

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `uploadURL` and `json`?

Comment: uploadURL is just the url +access token of the GitHub API for issues from my repo. The returned JSON is of all the issues (on the first page of the response) https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(json)`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination), you just add `?page=2` to the url or whatever page you need.

Comment: yea I know how to access the other pages, I was looking to find out how I know how many other pages there are

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, the headers are returned in the actual Ajax call. So I needed to assign it to a variable and then use "getResponseHeader()"

Basically:

```
var issues =[];
var ajsponse;

function buildIssueList(githubURL){
    ajsponse = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        url: githubURL,
          success: function(data){
              $.merge(issues, data);
              var link = ajsponse.getResponseHeader("Link");
              if (link.indexOf("next") !== -1) {
                      githubURL=link.substring(link.indexOf("<")+1,link.indexOf(">"));
                      buildIssueList(githubURL);
              }
              else{
                  printcompiled(issues);
              }
          }
        });
}
```